# Want to read string and output same string in assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm

I know string strings in memory isn't as easy as storing numbers or characters.  I'm trying to store the string with the .word directive and i know that is probably wrong. I'm, not sure how i would store the string in memory and then output it.  is the only option to store the string as a bunch of %c's and then outputting each character one by one? i'm trying to see if there is an easier way of doing that.  I tried the .string directive instead of .word but that was recognized as a valid directive.

```
.data

.balign 4

input_name: .asciz "enter name: "

.balign 4

output_name: .asciz "name entered : %s\n"

.balign 4

scan_pattern: .asciz "%s"

.balign 4

name_read: .word 0

.balign 4

return: .word 0

.global main

main:

        ldr r1, =return       

        str lr, [r1]


        ldr r0, =input_name

        bl printf


        ldr r0, =scan_pattern

        ldr r1, = name_read

        bl scanf


        ldr 0, =ouput_name

        ldr r1, =name_read

        ldr r1, [r1]

        bl printf


        ldr lr, =return

        ldr lr, [lr]

        bx lr
```

Comment: I am not really sure what the string is that you refer to, maybe the output from scanf? 
There are a bunch of other comments first:
There are a bunch of obvious typo's (e.g. ldr 0,=output_name) that may just be a copy/paste thing as I don't see how it builds.
The C methods need a stack - maybe that is already setup someplace.
The code is in the .data section, it usually goes into .text.
Instead of manipulating lr like that, either (a) just call 'b main' at the end to go back to the start.
(b) push lr onto the stack and pop it into pc.

Comment: Next up - allocating space. You can use the .space directive. Say you want to allocate 64 bytes for your string. 
`mystring: .space 64 ` assign scan_pattern to r0 and myspace to r1 for the call to scanf and again for the following printf.
Here is a cheat sheet for [gas ARM directives](http://www.coranac.com/files/gba/re-ejected-gasref.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The general method to solve such issues is "ask a compiler". You know, that what are you trying to do is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char str[1024];

int
main (void)
{
  scanf("%s", str);
  printf ("%s\n", str);
  return 0;
}
```

Now take any cross compiler. Not aware of your assembler syntax, it is strange, but question is tagged "gcc", so for this example lets take [Linaro GCC](https://launchpad.net/gcc-linaro):

```
gcc-linaro-2014.01/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -S -O2 test.c
```

Output assembly is:

```
    .thumb
    .file   "test.c"
    .section        .text.startup,"ax",%progbits
    .align  2
    .global main
    .thumb
    .thumb_func
    .type   main, %function
main:
    @ args = 0, pretend = 0, frame = 0
    @ frame_needed = 0, uses_anonymous_args = 0
    push    {r4, lr}
    movw    r4, #:lower16:str
    movt    r4, #:upper16:str
    movw    r0, #:lower16:.LC0
    mov     r1, r4
    movt    r0, #:upper16:.LC0
    bl      __isoc99_scanf
    mov     r0, r4
    bl      puts
    movs    r0, #0
    pop     {r4, pc}
    .size   main, .-main
    .comm   str,1024,4
    .section        .rodata.str1.4,"aMS",%progbits,1
    .align  2
.LC0:
    .ascii  "%s\000"
    .ident  "GCC: (crosstool-NG linaro-1.13.1-4.8-2014.01 - Linaro GCC 2013.11) 4.8.3 20140106 (prerelease)"
    .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",%progbits
```

I think everything is clear -- you can see `.comm` directive for string buffer and `.ascii` for printf pattern.

On your compiler everything might change, but I outlining method. First look at compiler-generated stuff, next write in assembly by yourself.